Server Vultr - CloudFlare encrypt
I use cloudFlare and Vultr server.
From the client to CloudFlare I know it is encrypted, but how can I be sure that from CloudFlare to the Vultr server it is also encrypted? Does anyone know of any kind of test?

You would need to enable SSL on the server somehow, and configure Cloudflare to use Strict SSL mode.

It can only be completely encrypted if you use Full Strict SSL in Cloudflare's SSL settings. Please refer to the link below
https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/origin-configuration/ssl-modes/full-strict/
